# How can I shorten or serialize fields in similar JSON objects by means of Node.js and NPM modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, npm

As I can using standard Node tools.js or NPM modules perform serialization of the following type. There can be more than one object with the property **"type":"ANY_TYPE"**.

`Raw Json` - https://pastebin.com/NL7A8amD

`Result Json` - https://pastebin.com/AScG7g1R

Thank you for your answers! Also sorry for bad English, if you see errors please correct me!

Comment: kindly clear your question. what you want and what you get. are you getting raw Json and want to change it on Result json

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this! I hope, I understand you right and you want this.

```js
const RawJson = [{"type":"A_TYPE","value":"foo"},{"type":"A_TYPE","value":"bar"},{"type":"B_TYPE","value":"qux"},{"type":"C_TYPE","value":[10000,19999],"name":"1xxxx"}];

const modifiedArray = (data) => {
 return data.map((d) =>  { return {"type": d.type, "value": data.filter(x => x.type === d.type).map(v => v.value)}; });
}

console.log(modifiedArray(RawJson));
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost it! But not only should duplicate objects.

Comment: OK, figured out how to delete duplicate objects. I'll mark your comment as an answer. Thanks again!